# String Split only returns first entry

Tags: sql, sql-server, split

I am trying to make a procedure for internal usage only part of it where you can add a string of tags separated by comma.

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE AddService
    @ServiceName AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Location AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Description AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @PermissionType AS INT,
    @Tags AS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @ServiceId AS INT

    INSERT INTO Services(NAME,LOCATION,DESCRIPTION,PERMISSIONTYPE) VALUES(@ServiceName,@Location,@Description,@PermissionType)
    SET @ServiceId = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY())

    DECLARE @TagSplit TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1),DATA VARCHAR(MAX))
    INSERT @TagSplit VALUES(SUBSTRING(@Tags,0,CHARINDEX(',',@Tags)))

    WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @TagSplit)
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @TempId AS INT
       DECLARE @Tag AS VARCHAR(MAX)

       SET @TempId = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @TagSplit)
       SET @Tag = (SELECT TOP 1 DATA FROM @TagSplit)

       INSERT INTO Tags VALUES(@ServiceId,@Tag)

       DELETE FROM @TagSplit WHERE ID = @TempId
    END
END
GO
```

But when I look in my "Tags" table, given the `@Tags` string "some,thing" only "some" is added, but not "thing". I think I might just be misunderstanding how to do proper string splitting in SQL.

This is the part that doesn't work correctly:

```
WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM @TagSplit)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TempId AS INT
    DECLARE @Tag AS VARCHAR(MAX)

    SET @TempId = (SELECT TOP 1 ID FROM @TagSplit)
    SET @Tag = (SELECT TOP 1 DATA FROM @TagSplit)

    INSERT INTO Tags VALUES(@ServiceId,@Tag)

    DELETE FROM @TagSplit WHERE ID = @TempId
END
```

Any help?

Comment: Why not use a data type *designed* for holding multiple values, such as a table or xml, rather than giving yourself a string containing commas?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I just thought it was easier, given that the way this will be used is just right clicking on the procedure in the Database Manager and click "Execute".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using a CSV Splitter table valued function by Jeff Moden

```
create function [dbo].[delimitedsplit8K] (
      @pstring varchar(8000)
    , @pdelimiter char(1)
  )
returns table with schemabinding as
 return
  with e1(N) as (
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all 
    select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1 union all select 1
  )
  , e2(N) as (select 1 from e1 a, e1 b)
  , e4(N) as (select 1 from e2 a, e2 b)
  , ctetally(N) as (
    select top (isnull(datalength(@pstring),0)) 
      row_number() over (order by (select null)) from e4
  )
  , ctestart(N1) as (
    select 1 union all
    select t.N+1 from ctetally t where substring(@pstring,t.N,1) = @pdelimiter
  )
  , ctelen(N1,L1) as (
    select s.N1,
      isnull(nullif(charindex(@pdelimiter,@pstring,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000)
    from ctestart s
  )
 select itemnumber = row_number() over(order by l.N1)
      , item       = substring(@pstring, l.N1, l.L1)
   from ctelen l
;
go
```

splitting strings reference:

- [Tally OH! An Improved SQL 8K “CSV Splitter” Function - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/)
- [Splitting Strings : A Follow-Up - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/08/t-sql-queries/splitting-strings-follow-up)
- [Split strings the right way – or the next best way - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings)
- [**`string_split()`** in SQL Server 2016 : Follow-Up #1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2016/04/sql-server-2016/string-split-follow-up-1)

Then your procedure becomes this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddService
    @ServiceName AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Location AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @Description AS VARCHAR(MAX),
    @PermissionType AS INT,
    @Tags AS VARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
    set nocount, xact_abort on;

    DECLARE @ServiceId AS INT;

    INSERT INTO Services(NAME,LOCATION,DESCRIPTION,PERMISSIONTYPE) 
    VALUES(@ServiceName,@Location,@Description,@PermissionType)

    SET @ServiceId = (SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY());

    insert into tags
    select @ServiceId, s.Item
    from [dbo].[delimitedsplit8K](@Tags,',') s;
end
go
```

Comment: This seems very complicated. From most of the solutions I found, it didn't look nearly this complicated. Are you sure this function is necessary?

Comment: @Vipar If you are using sql server 2016, you can use `string_split()` instead. Otherwise, this is one of the best methods without using a CLR function. If you want other options for pre-2016 string splitting, there are plenty in the articles I reference.

Comment: I went with another and simpler solution in the end, but I'll take yours as the correct one.